# Multiple http Requests AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, angular-promise

I consume a RESTful Service in Multiple Steps.

First I send a GET Request and receive a List of URIs, which I then follow in a for-each Loop to make my second REST Call.

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
var results = [];

APICall.getAllObjects(id).then(function(data){ 
   angular.forEach(data.data, function( value, key){
       APICall.getIndiviualObject(value).then(function(result)
       {
          results.push(result); //put Indiviual Objects in Array   
          deferred.resolve({objects: result});
       });
   });
});

return deferred.promise;
```

Unfortunately this only returns a Single Element, even when there are multiple Objects returned. I have no Idea how to resolve this - Granted Promises are relatively new for me...

Any Ideas on how to make this a proper Asynchronous Call?

Comment: $q.all is your friend here.

Answer (score 1):

I would try this.
Gather ALL your promises, and then wait until they all complete.

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
var results = [];

APICall.getAllObjects(id).then(function(data){ 
   var promises = [];

   angular.forEach(data.data, function( value, key){ 
       promises.push(APICall.getIndiviualObject(value).$promise);
   });

   $q.all(promises).then(function(results) {
       // here you should have all your Individual Object list in `results`
       deferred.resolve({objects: results});
   });
});

return deferred.promise;
```

Let me know if its work :)

Comment: It works as long as I remove the $promise after        promises.push(APICall.getIndiviualObject(value);

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `APICall.getIndividualObject` does only use the first value, you should be able to define your major getter like this:

```
var getAllById = function(id) {
  return APICall.getAllObjects(id).then(function(ids) {
    return $q.all(ids.map(APICall.getIndividualObject));
  });
};
```

So, what does it do exactly?

Returning a `Promise` in a `.then` still qualifies as a `Promise`. So does `$q.all`, simply returning a `Promise` for an `Array` of results.

(See https://github.com/kriskowal/q#chaining for Details on Chaining)

This allows you to use `getAllById` just as the promise you wanted to use in the first place:

```
getAllById(1337).then(function(results) {
  console.log('It worked!', results);
}, function(err) {
  console.error('Something bad happened!', err);
});
```

Hope that helps.